# Unmarshal flat XML to go data structure

Tags: xml, go

I have a flat XML structure which I am trying to unmarshal into a go data structure. I am trying to find a way to get the list of items(item-name) in each bucket from the
below XML i.e.- bucket1 = [apple,orange,grapes], bucket2= [apple,mangoes].

When I tried to unmarshal the xml into below go data structure, I was able to get the list of bucketnames and items, but I am unable to map the list of items to their respective buckets as each bucket can have many items.
Is there a way to achieve this requirement from this xml by changing the go data structure? I don't have control over the structure of the XML so I can't change the it to suit my requirement.
I am new to go and I'd appreciate any inputs here.

```
type buckets struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name `xml:"buckets"`
    BucketName []string `xml:"bucket-name"`
    ItemName   []string `xml:"item-name"`
    Weight     []string `xml:"weight"`
    Quantity   []string `xml:"quantity"`
}
        
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <buckets>
       <bucket-name>bucket1</bucket-name>
       <item-name>apple</item-name>
       <weight>500</weight>
       <quantity>3</quantity>
       <item-name>orange</item-name>
       <weight>500</weight>
       <quantity>2</quantity>
       <item-name>grapes</item-name>
       <weight>800</weight>
       <quantity>1</quantity>
       <bucket-name>bucket2</bucket-name>
       <item-name>apple</item-name>
       <weight>500</weight>
       <quantity>3</quantity>
       <item-name>mangoes</item-name>
       <weight>400</weight>
       <quantity>2</quantity>
    </buckets>
```

Comment: You'll probably want to implement a custom unmarshaler and decode by tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be achieved by using a custom `xml.UnmarshalXML` and manually mapping the buckets to a Go struct.

The code described below assumes that the XML elements come in the same *order* as the example provided.

First of all we have the structs as described on the question:

```
type Buckets struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"buckets"`
    Buckets []*Bucket
}

type Bucket struct {
    BucketName string `xml:"Bucket-name"`
    Items      []*Item
}

type Item struct {
    Name     string `xml:"item-name"`
    Weight   int    `xml:"weight"`
    Quantity int    `xml:"quantity"`
}
```

Next we will need to implement the [Unmarshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Unmarshaler) interface by implementing the `UnmarshalXML` method for the `Buckets` struct. This method is going to get called when we call the `xml.Unmarhsal` and passing as destination a `Buckets` struct.

```
func (b *Buckets) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    b.XMLName = start.Name

    var currentBucket *Bucket
    var currentItem *Item
    for {
        t, err := d.Token()
        if t == nil {
            // append the last bucket before exiting
            b.Buckets = append(b.Buckets, currentBucket)
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        switch se := t.(type) {
        case xml.StartElement:
            switch se.Name.Local {
            case "Bucket-name":
                // check if currentBucket is nil, it is necessary for the first time that
                // is going to run. Otherwise, append the last bucket to the slice and reset it
                if currentBucket != nil {
                    b.Buckets = append(b.Buckets, currentBucket)
                }
                currentBucket = &Bucket{}

                if err := d.DecodeElement(&currentBucket.BucketName, &se); err != nil {
                    return err
                }
            case "item-name":
                currentItem = &Item{}
                if err := d.DecodeElement(&currentItem.Name, &se); err != nil {
                    return err
                }
            case "weight":
                if err := d.DecodeElement(&currentItem.Weight, &se); err != nil {
                    return err
                }
            case "quantity":
                if err := d.DecodeElement(&currentItem.Quantity, &se); err != nil {
                    return err
                }

                // since quantity comes last append the item to the bucket,  and reset it
                currentBucket.Items = append(currentBucket.Items, currentItem)
                currentItem = &Item{}
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

What we are essentially doing is looping over the XML elements and mapping them to our struct with our custom logic. I won't go into great details about `d.Token()` and `xml.StartElement`, you can always read the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml) for more.

Now let's break down the above method:

- When we meet an element with name `Bucket-name` we know that a new bucket is following, so append the already processed one (we have to check for `nil` since the first time there won't be any processed) to the slice and set `currentBucket` to a new Bucket (the one we are going to process).
- When we meet an element with name `item-name` we know that a new item is following so set `currentItem` to a new Item.
- When we meet an element with name `quantity` we know that this is the last element that belongs to the `currentItem`, so append it to the `currentBucket.Items`
- When `t` finally becomes nil it indicates the end of the input stream, but since we are appending a bucket whenever we meet a new one, the last one (or if there is only a single bucket) won't get appended. So, before we `break` we need to append the last proccesed one.

**Notes:**

- You could totally avoid the `Buckets` struct and create a function to handle the unmarhsaling by making use of the `xml.Decoder` like that:

```
func UnmarshalBuckets(rawXML []byte) []*Bucket {
    // or any io.Reader that points to the xml data
    d := xml.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(rawXML))
    ...
}
```

**Disclaimers:**

- I know the code above feels a bit sketchy and I am sure that you can improve it. Feel free to play with it and implement the custom logic in a more readable way.
- There should be some edge cases that I didn't cover or are not present in the example provided. You should analyze your XML and try (if possible) to cover them.
- As already mentioned, the code is heavily dependant in the order of the XML elements.

Working example at [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/iR94acRMrW-)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mkopriva. Go's annotations are optimized for XML used for identically-structured data records. Using them for mixed content is like putting a saddle on a cow. plug: I have written code for handling mixed content that is on GitHub and I'd welcome feedback.